# How to add a delay with which a google places autocomplete api is called?

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want to delay the call to google places autocomplete api by 500 ms after every change in search-box character.

This is the code I am using :

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { StandaloneSearchBox, LoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const PlaceComponent = () => {
   
    return (
        <LoadScript
            googleMapsApiKey="API_KEY"
            libraries={["places"]}
        >
            <StandaloneSearchBox
                onLoad={(ref) => (inputRef.current = ref)}
                onPlacesChanged={handlePlaceChanged}
            >
                <input
                    id="location"
                    name="location"
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter Location"
                />
            </StandaloneSearchBox>
        </LoadScript>
    );
};

export default PlaceComponent;
```

Comment: You *should* use the Places Autocomplete service which uses [session tokens](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#session_tokens). Not sure what exists for React.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
//your api call
},5000)
```